# Fatal Exception main at onclick

Tags: java, android

Im getting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main at com.test.megatest.Main4Activity$1.onClick(Main4Activity.java:37).

Ive read tons of posts on this forum but I cant figure out what Im missing,

This is the Main4Activity.java:

```
package com.test.megatest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText inputText;
TextView response;
    Button saveButton, readButton;

    private String filename = "SampleFile.txt";
    private String filepath ="MyFileStorage";
    File myExternalFile;
    String myData ="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

        inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myInputText);
        response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);

        saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveExternalStorage);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);  //LINE 37
                    fos.write(inputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                inputText.setText("");
                response.setText("SampleFile.txt saved to somewhere..");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can someone here just point me in the right direction? :)

Answer (score 1):

The file you try to open an output stream for is NULL.
You declared it as a member but never initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Main4Activity has a "File" variable:

```
File myExternalFile;
```

But without assigning any object/value to that variable You are trying to use it in:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
```

Obviously you will get an Exception for that :P

> You should initialise "myExternalFile" using any of the 4 public constructors specified at [java.io.File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) (depending on your use case).
>   
> For example:

```
// If you need a "Persistent" file in private directory of your application
//
myExternalFile = new File(this.getFilesDir() ,"name_of_your_file.txt");
//
// or
// If you need a "Cache" file
myExternalFile = new File(this.getCacheDir() ,"name_of_your_file.txt");
```

> Locations of above files on your Android filesystem is:
>   
>  **# Persistent:** /data/data/com.test.megatest/files **or**
>   
> (Any File Manager App) /Android/data/com.test.megatest/files
>   
>  **# Cache:** /data/data/com.test.megatest/cache **or**
>   
> (Any File Manager App) /Android/data/com.test.megatest/files

**Reference:** 

 1) [java.io.FileOutputStream -> FileOutputStream (File file) public constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File))

"Creates a file output stream to write to the ***file represented by the specified File object***"

Comment: Thanks!

Soooooo on to the next retarded question, once I have clicked "save" where can I then acctually find the file SampleFile.txt ?

Comment: @Rasmus Added the "locations" at end of my answer. If you have any other query Pass them on :)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize file as

```
File myExternalFile=new File("SampleFile.txt");
```